# How to integrate a max function by sympy in python?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to integrate a max function by sympy in python. However, it seems sympy cannot deal with such a function with relational comparison.

```
import sympy
def func(x):
    return max(x,0)
x = sympy.symbols(x)
sympy.integrate(func(x),(x,-1,1))
```

Run the above code, it gives the error info:

```
  File "<ipython-input-11-2630b8af4afe>", line 2, in func
    return max(x,0)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 304, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

It seems sympy cannot deal with functions with comparison. It gives the same error when I try a piecewise function, which also includes a process of comparison.

Answer (score 2):

SymPy uses uppercase and lowercase names to refer (often) to functions and classes. When you get a "truth value" error it means that something that could give a True or False answer didn't (like `if x < 1: print('less than 1')`). If `x` is a Symbol then `x < 1` remains a `Lt(x, 1)` object.

In your case, the function `max` tried to compare `x` and 0 and it couldn't get True or False comparison. Use the `Max` object instead to see your integral evaluate:

```
>>> from sympy import Max
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> integrate(Max(x,0),(x,-1,1))
1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- The first parameter to `sympy.symbols` should be a string to represent the variable. For example: `x = sympy.symbols('x')`.
- `max` is a Python function. A sympy function should be used instead: `sympy.Max`

```py
import sympy

def func(x):
    return sympy.Max(0, x)

x = sympy.symbols('x')
sympy.integrate(func(x), (x, -1, 1))
```

Also piecewise functions can be integrated:

```
def func2(x):
    return sympy.Piecewise((-x, x < 0), (x * x, x < 0.5), (x * x * x, True))

sympy.integrate(func2(x), (x, -1, 1)) # 0.776041666666667
```